# Invalid read with list iterator but not with vector iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, runtime-error, wrapper

I have an stl container wrapper and I need to iterate. If I wrap a `vector` everything works fine. However, I would prefer to wrap a `list`, but if I do so, I get an invalid read. This is a part of output from valgrind:

```
Invalid read of size 8 std::_List_const_iterator<sim_mob::TripRequestMessage>::operator++() (stl_list.h:235)
```

This is the definition of my wrapper:

```
template <class T> class Group
{
public:
    Group(){};

    ~Group(){elements.clear();};

    using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;

    void insert(const T &r)
    {
        elements.push_back(r);
    }

protected:
    //aa!!: If the access is only sequential, It would be preferrable to use list instead
    //          of vector. But if I use list, I get  Invalid read of size 8 std::_List_const_iterator<sim_mob::TripRequestMessage>::operator++() (stl_list.h:235)
    //          at runtime
    std::vector<T> elements;
};
```

and how I use it:

```
for (Group<MyClass>::iterator it = mygroup.begin(); it != mygroup.end(); ++it)
 //... do something
```

The problem seems to be in `++it`. My gcc version is 4.8.5

Comment: That doesn't compile. Your `Group` class doesn't even have a `begin` method.

Comment: Recommendation: Post a [mcve] of the `list` version. Could be something going wrong in `mygroup.begin();` and `mygroup.end();` and no way for us to know.

Comment: *"how I use it..."* That may be how you use *something*, but not how you use what you posted. It has no `begin()` or `end()` members. Don't post fantasy code unless it [replicates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is in `//... do something`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the call to `elements.clear()` in the destructor is not needed. Containers take care of themselves.